# Linux driver development: how to investigate copy_to_user() timing?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm developing a Linux driver and have found in some circumstances `copy_to_user()` takes much longer than expected.  I guess it may be waiting on the `mm->mmap_sem semaphore`, perhaps?  There also seems to be extra CPU activity in the unfavorable cases.

I would be grateful for advice on how to investigate this further and/or what to do about it.

More detail:

The platform has an **I7** with 2 physical cores running at 2.5GHz, with a **32-bit X86** build of **Linux 2.6.32**.  The driver accepts data over **PCI Express** and supplies it to user space through a character device.  A test process runs at a high priority, reading into a buffer that I think is paged in.  The goal is to support quite high data rates, currently a few hundred megabits per second and ultimately about 1Gbps, sustained for at least a few seconds.

My test involves reading **25MB** of data in a second or so.  With the right data set, the driver can receive reliably at **100Mbps** or **400Mbps**.  With slightly different **100Mbps** data, it sporadically fails.  Neither the driver nor the test tool cares about the content of the data, so I would expect it to make no difference.  There may be statistical differences in arrival times and burstiness, but nothing large enough to stand out when reading through lists of timestamps.

The immediate cause of the problem is overflowing the receive buffer (about 1MB).  This is due to the process reading too slowly, which in turn is the result of `copy_to_user()` taking a long time.  A copy typically transfers a few hundred bytes.  With the good **100Mbps** input this function returns reasonably quickly, usually well under a microsecond judging by the cycle count.  With the problematic **100Mbps** data, some calls take as long as 10 milliseconds, and this can happen multiple times, not just a one-off.

The **I7Z** tool ([link here](http://code.google.com/p/i7z/)) indicates a difference in CPU activity.  When processing the good 100Mbps data, one core spends most of its time in power state `C1` and the other is mainly in `C6` (low power).  With the bad data, one core is mainly in `C0` (the most active state), the other may spend anything from 0 to 70% of its time in `C1` and the rest mostly in `C6`.  So it looks like it's doing the normal processing plus a lot of extra `C0`.  Maybe a lot of spinning?

Pseudocode summary of the relevant parts of the driver and test tool:

```
pseudo_interrupt_handler()
{
        if(DMA finished) {
                advance head;
                wake_up_interruptible();
        }
        if(new data && no DMA in progress) {
                start DMA into head;
        }
}

pseudo_file_read(filp, user buf, size)
{
        wait_event_interruptible(head != tail);

        while(head != tail && space in user buf) {
                copy_to_user(from tail);
                advance tail;
        }
        return total copied;
}

pseudo_test_process()
{
        buffer = malloc(25MB);
        write to each page in buffer; // page in

        while(buffer not full) {
                read(STDIN_FILENO, position in buffer, 4000B);
                advance position in buffer
        }
}
```

I have no satisfactory workaround at present.  I could buffer more data in the driver, but that can only help with temporary delays.  This problem appears to be slowing things down systematically and limiting the overall data rate.  If there's no other solution, mmap would be possible, but that would require substantial changes to the existing application software.

Update (January).  Thanks for the suggestions.  I'm now working around the problem with some enlargement and reorganisation of the buffers.  We now use a smaller number of larger `copy_to_user()` operations, so a small proportion of slow ones have less impact.

Update (June).  As suggested, I've implemented an mmap() interface, which does indeed circumvent the problem.  No more copy_to_user() bottleneck.

Comment: Yet, mmap is the way to go when high performance is concerned. Either this, or make your driver behave like a block device (may be the easiest option) - the kernel will do a lot of heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 0):

copy_to_user() and copy_from_user() always involve copying data, and this is intrinsically a slow process (depending on the point of view, of course). For maximum performance, the **only** way is 'mmap'. See the extract below from [here](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html#s8)!

> Memory mapping is the only way to transfer data between user and kernel spaces that does not involve explicit copying, and is the fastest way to handle large amounts of data.